3 white brothers: an excon, a war veteran and a young urban artist
This is probably from late 80s or early 90s. The 3 brothers are adults but still live at their parents with family problems. The war vet is timid and somewhat crazy, spends time alone in his room and wears army gear all the time. The young one is a street artist and goes out to paint walls at night. The three kept to themselves.
I remember a scene where the older brother sits on a rainy night on a swing at the park, wearing a hoodie, warming up for a fight. At the end of the movie the exconvict brother gets killed by some gang, but the older exmilitary brother avenges his death silently one night. That's all I can recall. Thanks.

Deja vu... Did you ask this here before? (I do have a match in mind, though.)

It is Bullet, thanks a lot. And yes, I posted this months ago, and didn't get an asnwer back then.

I had a feeling. Oddly, I couldn't remember it the first time, but seeing this again now suddenly made me think of Rourke. Memories are weird. ;)

This sounds like Bullet from 1996 with Mickey Rourke.

Butch "Bullet" Stein is a Jewish junkie from the mean streets of Brooklyn, is paroled after eight years in prison. [...] the only people in Butch's corner are his two brothers, the mentally-unhinged Vietnam War veteran Louis and aspiring artist Ruby

Bullet is killed in the end and Louis avenges his death. Here's a trailer:


 
